# C# paint event does nothing

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

I'm having a label with a `paint event` this is my code:

```
public void draw(MouseEventArgs e, User user)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Tag = user;
    label.Paint += Label_Paint;
    label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
    label.Width = 50;
    label.Height = 40;
    label.Name = user.name;
    label.Text = user.name;
    this.mainPanel.Controls.Add(label);
}

private void Label_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    Label label = (Label)sender;
    g.DrawEllipse(p, label.Location.X, label.Location.Y, 300, 300);
}
```

My goal is to draw a oval around the label and show it on my `mainPanel`. The label shows up in my `mainPanel` but no oval is being drawn.

I'm using `WinForm`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to set the `AutoSize` property of the `Label` to `false`

Comment: @Dr. Fre thanks but that does not work.

Comment: The label has a size of 50 to 40 and you are drawing a elipse with the size of 300 to 300 somewhere in its canvas. You are not going to see that.

Comment: You are trying to color outside of the lines.  If you want it *around* the label then it has to be the label's Parent control that draws it.  So use mainPanel's Paint event.